# Use of past perfect with since

Tags: past-perfect

"He hadn't been to school since last week."

As a native english speaker, I sense this sentence is wrong, but I can't figure out why, other than that 'last week' seems to posit a vantage point of the present.

However, 'he hadn't been to school since the accident' seems perfectly fine, so if the accident happened last week, why are these two not interchangeable?

Comment: @Trick I haven't heard the term 'pluperfect' used in donkey's years!

Comment: @BillJ Plusquamperfect, if you prefer.